# How can I create a new array from the array returned by a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have a method to shuffle arrays, but it's not working and I don't know how to fix it now. How can I create a new array in main from the array returned by `shuffleArray` as I can't assign the shuffled array to a new array and it's giving me the same index for the elements?

```
using namespace std;

template <class T> T min (T array, T size){
    int min=array[0];
    for(int i=1;i<size;i++){
        if(array[i]<min){min=array[i];}
    }
return min;
}

template <class T> T indexOf (T array[], const int size, T value){

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(array[i]==value){return value;}
    }
    return -1;
    }

template <class T> T shuffleArray (T array[], T size){

    T* Array2 = new T[size];

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
       Array2[i]=array[i];
    }

    random_shuffle(&Array2[0],&Array2[size]);

    return *Array2;
}

int main(){

    int a[]= {1,2,3,4,5};
    int index = indexOf(a, 5, 3);

    cout << endl << "The index is:" << shuffleArray(a, 5)<<endl;
    cout << endl << "The index is:" << index<<endl;
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Why are you making a copy of the array in the function?  Just shuffle the array you pass into the function and that will be reflected in the array from the call site.

Comment: `return *Array2;` is a bad idea, you may be left with memory leaks.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is a bad habit to get into and if you can stop now you might avoid a whole lot of headaches in the future. The `std::` prefix is there for a reason: It avoids conflict with your own classes, structures and variables.

Comment: @NathanOliver So which pointer to use for the `delete` after the function call?

Comment: You will need to have the function return the size of the array or the number of elements to copy.  Using `std::vector` will help solve these issues, as `std::vector` maintains the capacity of the container.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oops.  You were right.  Need to return the pointer

Comment: NathanOliver, I stopped trying to make a copy of the array inside the function.


    template <class T> T shuffleArray (T array[], T size){
        random_Shuffle (&array[0], &array[size]);
     }


When I run the code again, the index function is returning -1, which means it can;t find anything, not that their position changed. Any idea why?

Comment: it makes no sense to template these function as long as you are passing the parameters `T size` as T. This will  make these template valid only for integer types. Recommended to change the prototypes to `size_t size`.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** Use std container as `std::array`, they have appropriate copy constructors and save you some headache. By the way `std::array` is also not slower as a raw array (it is basically the raw array, but wrapped in a class and given some nice member functions to work with it).

**Detailed Answer:** I am not entirely sure, what you like to print to `std::cout`. But most likely it should be the position of `3` before and after shuffling. Then the code should look like this (to compile with `std=c++11` for use of `constexpr` and `auto`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // std::min, std::find and std::random_shuffle
#include <array> // use std::array instead of raw pointers

// using namespace std; Bad idea, as tadman points out in comment

// use std::min instead of
// template <class T> T min (T array, T size)

// use std::find instead of
// template <class T> T indexOf (T array[], const int size, T value){

// T is not the value_type of the array, but the array iteself. Works also for all other std containers with random access iterators
template<class T> T shuffleArray(T array) // array is copied here
{
    // shuffle
    std::random_shuffle(array.begin(), array.end());

    // return copy of array
    return array;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int numberToFind = 3; // constexpr is not necessary, but the variable seems not intented to change in this code
    // use standard container instead of raw array
    std::array<int,5> a = {1,2,3,4,5};

    // iterator to numberToFind in a
    auto it = std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), numberToFind); // auto deduces the type, so you do not have to write std::array<int,t>::iterator and by the way the code is more flexible for changes

    // shuffle a and store result in aShuffled
    auto aShuffled = shuffleArray(a);

    // iterator to numberToFind in aShuffled
    auto itShuffled = std::find(aShuffled.begin(), aShuffled.end(), numberToFind);

    // pointer arithmetics give the index
    std::cout << "The index before shuffling is:" << it - a.begin() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The index after  shuffling is:" << itShuffled - aShuffled.begin() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As some comments already tell you, a few tips for the future:

- Use std containers instead of raw pointers of raw arrays
- Use well tested algorithms from the standard library instead of writing your own, unless you have very specific needs
- `auto` makes live very easy in C++11 to handle also the iterator types. By the way you have to change almost nothing to use std::vector instead of std::array. The first declaration is enough.
- Always when you use a `new` there has to be a `delete`. Otherwise you create a memory leak. Again this can be generally avoided by using the standard container.
- Use descriptive names instead of literals. This makes your code more clear and readable.